# How to Prove $\frac{1}{n}-\ln(\frac{n}{n-1})<0$ using Taylor's Expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am attempting to prove $\frac{1}{n}-\ln(\frac{n}{n-1})<0$ using Taylor's expansion for the natural log term. I found if we let

$f(x) = \ln(\frac{x}{x-1})$ then,

$f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{\binom{x}{1}x^{n-1}+\dots+\binom{n}{n}x-1}{x^{n}(x-1)^n}$ where every $x$ term with an even power is negative.

If we expand about $2$ the first few terms would be

$\ln(2) -\frac{1}{2}(x-2)+\frac{3}{8}(x-2)^{2}-\frac{19}{648}(x-2)^{3}+\dotsb$

I chose $2$ because $1$ is out of the domain for $f(x)$ so this seemed to be the next easiest value. From here I was having trouble moving forward though. I was hoping something would cancel in the expansion but it does not seem to come out nicely. Does anyone have an idea where to go next to prove the original statement?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

$$\ln\frac n{n-1}=-\ln\left(1-\frac1n\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{kn^k}>\frac1n$$
for $n\ge2$. Here we use the Maclaurin series
$$-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}k.$$

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't see that. I definitely over complicated this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we have $$\log\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)=-\log\left(1-\frac1n\right)$$

From the extended mean value theorem, there exists a number $\xi \in (0,x)$ such that

$$-\log(1-x)=x+\frac12\frac{1}{(1-\xi)^2}x^2>x$$

Letting $x=1/n$, $n> 1$ we see that

$$-\log\left(1-\frac1n\right)> \frac1n$$